# De-selecting " Promote Tumblr!" not working anymore

Tags: tumblr

It seems Tumblr has added a new  "Promote tumblr!" button, however de-selecting it in the advance options isn't working now. anyone have a fix for this? it's annoying because it's blocking my navigation and would like to remove it

Answer (score 1):

```
.tmblr-iframe--desktop-loggedin-controls.iframe-controls--desktop,
.tmblr-iframe, 
.tmblr-iframe--desktop-loggedin-controls,
.iframe-controls--desktop {
    display:none;
}
```

Try adding this to your style tag.

Comment: Great that worked! quick question, how could i move my header image up? it seems to be aligned a little low on mobile http://theslyshow.com